# I am trying to explain the use of the code in my program but I have no idea what error = [] actually does?

Tags: python

```
print'Your password must contain the following.. \n\n - at least 1 uppercase letter\n - at least 1 lowercase letter \n - at least 1 number \n - at least 7 characters' # Tells the user what the password requires
password = 0                                                    #Sets the password at 0 , gives an entry point into the while loop
while password <7:                                              #This while loop, while the password count is less than 7 execute the following
    s=raw_input('\nPlease choose a password: ')                 #Giving the password a variable
    errors = []                                                 #?????????????????????
    if not any(x.isupper() for x in s):                         #This is testing if there is NOT any uppercase characters in the string
        errors.append('\nERROR Your password needs at least 1 capital letter')
    if not any (x.islower() for x in s):
        errors.append('\nERROR Your password needs at least 1 lower case letter')
    if not any (x.isdigit() for x in s):
        errors.append('\nERROR Your password needs at least 1 number')
    if len(s)< 7:
        print '\nERROR Your password needs to be at least 7 characters'
    if errors:
        print '\n'.join(errors)
    if (any(x.isupper() for x in s) and any(x.islower() for x in s) and any(x.isdigit() for x in s) and len(s) >= 7):
        print '\n\nGreat, your all set up and ready to go. \n\nYour login:',login, '\nYour password:',s
        password = password +7
```

Comment: quick & dirty explanation: you are assigning an empty list to `errors`. Effectively deleting all list elements that was in there before.

Answer (score 2):

In python `[]` means creating an empty list.
You can also use `error = list()` it is also the same.
Then you are assigning that list to a variable name called `error`:

```
error = []
```

Later, you use `error.append()` which means you put elements at the end of the list referenced to the name `error`.

Comment: @AmaChurLOL and it's probably worth noting that since you've done all the checks (`isupper()`, `islower()` and `isdigit()` to append error messages to your list), then just checking `if not error` is sufficient enough to know that your password meets your criteria.